# Where do I configure the client certificates for linphone?

Tags: ssl-certificate, linphone

I want to enable TLS transportation in linphone(using Windows OS) and mutually authenticate the server and the client with linphone being the client.But inorder to do so,I need to configure my client certificate in linphone.Can somebody please tell me how to configure this in linphone?I dont see anything in the preferences part either unlike PhonerLite.